# How to render objects in smooth mode in Maya

Tags: 3d, maya

There is `smooth` mode (`3` on keyboard if I'm correct) to show objects 'smooth' in the viewport, but when I render it, there is no smoothing.

What should I do in order to get a smooth render?

I've tried to look for tools for smoothing, but was unable to find anything. In `3ds max` I could achieve it by applying the modifier `Turbosmooth`.

Comment: What renderer are you using?

Comment: I'm using mentalray

Comment: If you're using mental ray, it should render smoothed automatically. My answer can't possibly be helpful can it?

Comment: It is helpful, i was about to switch to Vray, so any info is welcome :)

Comment: I've confirmed, Mental Ray doesn't require anything special. If it's smooth mesh in the preview, it'll render that way by default. The only way I could break it was if I unchecked `Use Preview Level for Rendering` in the shape attributes, and set Render Division Levels to 0. I'm guessing you didn't do that

Comment: SOmehow, my render switched back to maya render instead of mental ray, so that caused an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using V-Ray. It's the most popular renderer that doesn't by default inherit from the smooth mesh settings.

1. So, you've made a cube, and pressed <kbd>3</kbd> to smooth it:

   [image: viewport smoothed]
2. When you render, it isn't smooothed:

   [image: render not smoothed]
3. You have two options.

   - Enable subdivision on the shape (attribute editor for the shape node):
     [image: shape smoothing]
   - Globally tell V-Ray to render based on the viewport subdivision (render settings):
     [image: global smoothing]
4. Either option will smooth your render:

   [image]

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with when I get back to the office in another 9 hours

Comment: Hey in my attribute editor under - attributes- there is no vray option do you know why this is?
thanks

Comment: @austin V-Ray is a third party renderer (plugin). If you haven't installed it properly you won't have the menu. Are you rendering in V-Ray?

Comment: i dont have v-ray option..:(((

Answer (score 1):

Or you can apply a Modify > Convert > Smooth Mesh Preview to Polygons on your mesh. It will then render properly on all renderers... but you'll lose the ability to further modify your object using smooth mesh.

Comment: Hi Laurent, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a subdivision approximation in mental ray and have smooth mesh preview on:

1. Go to windows rendering editors > mental ray > approximation editor.
2. There is a subdivision rollout in the approximation editor.
3. Under the subdivision rollout hit the create button.
4. Make sure smooth preview mesh is on in the attribute editor.
5. Render

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign!